# Excel: Check if cell value already exists in column, and then subtract and show another value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 sheets, first one with values assigned to certain names

[image]

And second one is a control list which I update everyday:

[image]

I want to get this updated list to show updated values while I add new rows, for example, if LEG "1" is already shown in the table, and I add a row at the bottom, value of "COR" (column D) should show value-SAL (column E). Here's an image of what I'm looking to achieve, made by hand for the example:

[image]

As you can see, in first place column D for LEG1 is 14, but as I take 7 off of it (SAL, column E) when I call the same value again in row 8, column D shows 7.

The same should happen if called it again at the bottom:

[image]

Hope you understand what I'm trying to explain, this is my first time here!

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: This is what I got until now:

[image]

```
----A----------B---------C
1---x----------8---------3
2---y----------9---------2
3---z----------7---------3
4---y----------7---------3
5---x----------5---------5
6---x----------5---------0
7---y----------4---------2
8---y----------2---------2
9---z----------4---------4
0---y----------2---------0
```

=============================================================

## EDIT: I'll try to clarify even more what I'm trying to achieve:

This is the initial table that you would see. As I explain in column headers, values are called from DATA sheet, to be later modified in BASE sheet:

[image]

As values are then called again on this table, newly added rows should check previous inputs and subtract them, in order to see how many "items" are available left to take (image shown below is manually edited, not actually working like this right now):

[image]

**Ames** answer almost got it, values are showing up as they should (with subtractions made) but there's a little "glitch" (should I call it like that?) that makes all previous values from that person change, and that isn't expected to happen:

[image]

If you know a little tweak that would make this 100% functional, would be highly appreciated.

Formula in use is: `=INDICE(DATA!C$2:C$7;COINCIDIR(A2;DATA!A$2:A$7;0))-SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO(D:D;A:A;A2)+D2`

In English: `=INDEX(DATA!C$2:C$7,MATCH(A2,DATA!A$2:A$7,0))-SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,A2)+D2`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried so far, and please inline your pictures, or recreate the tables using code-formatted text.

Comment: I can't embed images directly to the post as I don't have enough reputation. I'll add full image with my advance in formulas in OP.

Comment: Update done, sorry if it's not correct.

Comment: Here is a translation which might help someone find an answer: SI is IF, IGUAL is EXACT, BUSCARV is VLOOKUP, FALSO is FALSE, and Saldos is a worksheet name.

Comment: It's very confusing. you have sheet 1 and now you have sheet 2 which is the control sheet that you update but the changes is in sheet 2 as well???

Comment: Please let us know how do make the call, e.g. call "Leg1" again, do you mean all columns A,B,C,and E are editable for calling in Sheet2 except column D "Cor" is autopopulated and this is where you need help at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update (fix updating previous values):**

Try this - formula starting from cell D2:

```
=INDEX(I$2:I$7,MATCH(B2,G$2:G$7,0))-SUMIFS(E$2:E2,B$2:B2,B2)+E2
```

In Spanish:

```
=INDICE(I$2:I$7,COINCIDIR(B2,G$2:G$7,0))-SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO(E$2:E2,B$2:B2,B2)+E2
```

[image]

**update 2:**

Based on the new tabular format.

Formula for Column B (Name):

```
=INDEX(G$2:G$7,MATCH(A2,F$2:F$7,0))

=INDICE(G$2:G$7,COINCIDIR(A2,F$2:F$7,0))
```

Formula for Column C (Left):

```
=INDEX(H$2:H$7,MATCH(A2,F$2:F$7,0))-SUMIFS(D$2:D2,A$2:A2,A2)+D2

=INDICE(H$2:H$7,COINCIDIR(A2,F$2:F$7,0))-SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO(D$2:D2,A$2:A2,A2)+D2
```

[English-Spanish Excel Function Translation](http://www.piuha.fi/excel-function-name-translation/index.php?page=english-spanish.html)

End Result:
[image]

Comment: This one got so close! It almost hit the nail, but there's something missing. I'll update OP with advance and with an image to try and clarify even more. What's happening with your answer is that, as I add more rows of a certain "LEG", previous rows of that LEG are also modified, when (if possible) they souldn't.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it now.

Comment: Update to OP made!

Comment: Absolutely brilliant, marked as answered! I tried it and it works like a charm. Would you mind explaing a little bit? I got the INDEX part alright, but can't quite figure out how does the SUMIFS work to check previous rows. Thank you so much!

Comment: for Sumifs, the formula sweeps through fix from the first record (D$2) until current record (D#), and only sum Take of Legs that are similar to current record. But we do not really want to include this row's take. To simplify this at cell (C8): "Control of Leg1(14)"-"total of Leg1 until current row(14)"+"current row's take(7)". Hope that explains it.

Comment: the reason there was a glitch before is because sumifs sweeps past current row. and those Takes are not cancelled out thus changing the Left values of previous Legs when new Legs are added.

Comment: Hey Ames! Quick question, before starting a new thread asking this: Would it be possible to use filters and sorting options, without them affecting final results? If I use those as of now, considering that numbers work reading previous rows, all numbers go crazy lol

Comment: It won't work with the formulas. If the purpose of sorting and filtering is for reading, then you could just copy and paste as values in another sheet then filter/sort. Otherwise the formula is not independent of sorting.

Answer (score 0):

give this a try. paste into cell D8.

=VLOOKUP($B8,$B:$D,3,FALSE)-SUMIFS($E$1:$E7,$B$1:$B7,B8)